# During migration of couchdb from 1.6.1 to 2.3.1, due to memory issues couchup utility taking lot of time rebuild views

Tags: view, erlang, couchdb, rebuild

During my migration of couchdb from `1.6.1` to `2.3.1`, couchup utility is taking a lot of time to rebuild views. There are memory issues with couchup utility. The size of databases are in 500 GB range. It is taking forever. It has been almost 5 to 6 days and still not complete. Is there any way to speed it up?

When trying to do replicate, after 2-3 mins of couchup running, couchdb dies because of memory leak issues and again it starts. Replicate will take around 10 days. For replicate, it was showing progress bar but for rebuild views, it does not show progress bar. I don't know about the how much has been done.

The couchdb is installed in a RHEL Linux server.

Answer (score 1):

## reducing backlog growth:

As couchup encounters views that take longer than 5 seconds to rebuild, couchup is going to carry on calling additional view urls, triggering their rebuild. Once a number of long running view rebuilds are running even rebuilds that would have been shorter will take at least 5 seconds, leading to a large backlog. If individual databases are large or (map/reduce functions are very inefficient) it would probably be best to set the timeout to something like 5 minutes. If you see more than a couple:

```
 Timeout, view is processing. Moving on.
```

messages it is probably time to kill couchup and double the timeout.

## Observing Index growth

By default `view_index_dir` is the same as the database directory so if data is in `/var/lib/couchdb/shards` then `/var/lib/couchdb` is the configured directory and indexes are stored in `/var/lib/coucdh/.shards`. You can observe which index shard files are being created and growing or move `view_index_dir` somewhere separate for easier observation.

## What resources are running out?

You can tune couchdb in general, it is hard to say whether tuning is needed once the system is not rebuilding all indexes, etc.

In particular, you would want to look for and disable any autocompaction. Look at files in `/proc/[couchdb proc]` to figure out the effective fd limits and how many open files there are and whether the crash happens around a specific number of open files. Due to sharding the number of open files is usually a multiple of the number of those in earlier versions.

Look at memory growth and figure out if it is stabalizing enough to use swap to prevent the problem.

Comment: thanks for the response. I tried giving timeout to 5 mins but still the script fails after running for 1 min .It looks like it is again hitting performance issues. Even though CPU and mempory is bumped up 4 times.requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(111, 'Connection refused'))

Comment: What have you done to determine you are running out of memory? You can run out of file descriptors, etc.

Comment: {{nocatch,{os_process_error,{exit_status,1}}},[{couch_os_process,prompt,2,[{file,"src/couch_os_process.erl"},{line,59}]},{couch_query_servers,map_doc_raw,2,[{file,"src/couch_query_servers.erl"},{line,68}]},{couch_mrview_updater,'-map_docs/2-fun-0-',3,[{file,"src/couch_mrview_updater.erl"},{line,199}]},{lists,foldl,3,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1263}]},{couch_mrview_updater,map_docs,2,[{file,"src/couch_mrview_updater.erl"},{line,206}]}]}  Sometimes i see error message such as High memory watermark or worst memory user

Comment: What is the approximate relation between RAM size, db_size(shard_size,largest_doc_size)? You could try reducing the number of docs a view could process at a time, i.e.: `[view_updater] queue_item_cap = 100`

Comment: Thanks for your guidance @lossleader . I put below in local.ini [view_updater] min_writer_items = 10
min_writer_size = 2097152. But still is is not making difference. Again it checked for the memory and cpu using commands free -g , sar -u 5. for memory 70% is still available and for CPU 80 % is available. But when I run $top command, for  beam.smp process, it shows CPU% as 300%. As suggested, I created separate folder for view. I don't see any files getting created in the view folder. It does not look like memory or CPU related. There are 2 shards